# How to render (nearly) empty page without any overhead with Gatsby?

Tags: gatsby

Is it possible to render such html page with gatsby:

```
<html>
  <body>
    text
  </body>
</html>
```

i.e. that not a single overhead gatsby-specific symbol or external reference to anything would be rendered? In other words - can gatsby render completely empty page? By not using gatsby link and customizing html as in https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/custom-html/ would that be possible, or any other customizations are needed?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is the minimum response I've managed to achieve:

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html></html>
```

I've followed https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/custom-html/ and modified `html.js`. It suits my needs to have as light starting file as this.

Comment: tbh, that doesn't really make sense as you loose a lot of the performance optimizations that Gatsby implements, e.g. Gatsby Link, Inlining CSS etc. Gatsby will be faster than your customized site